# how can I add max-width by @for rule in sass based on column size?

Tags: css, sass

> I need to add max-width under flex same as I made column here by @for
> in scss

```
$columns: 12;


@for $i from 1 through $columns {
  .col-#{$i} {
    flex: 0 0 100% / $columns * $i;
```

**`here I need to add max-width based on column size`**

```
  }
  .col-offset-#{$i} {
    margin-left: 100% / $columns * $i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
    max-width: percentage($i / $columns); 
    or
    max-width: 100% / $columns * $i;
```

Here is the complete code

```
$columns: 12;


@for $i from 1 through $columns {
  .col-#{$i} {
    flex: 0 0 100% / $columns * $i;
    max-width: percentage($i / $columns);
  }
  .col-offset-#{$i} {
    margin-left: 100% / $columns * $i;
  }
}
```

This code will compile to

```css
.col-1 {
  flex: 0 0 8.3333333333%;
  max-width: 8.3333333333%;
}

.col-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.3333333333%;
}

.col-2 {
  flex: 0 0 16.6666666667%;
  max-width: 16.6666666667%;
}

.col-offset-2 {
  margin-left: 16.6666666667%;
}

.col-3 {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.col-offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  flex: 0 0 33.3333333333%;
  max-width: 33.3333333333%;
}

.col-offset-4 {
  margin-left: 33.3333333333%;
}

.col-5 {
  flex: 0 0 41.6666666667%;
  max-width: 41.6666666667%;
}

.col-offset-5 {
  margin-left: 41.6666666667%;
}

.col-6 {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.col-offset-6 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
  flex: 0 0 58.3333333333%;
  max-width: 58.3333333333%;
}

.col-offset-7 {
  margin-left: 58.3333333333%;
}

.col-8 {
  flex: 0 0 66.6666666667%;
  max-width: 66.6666666667%;
}

.col-offset-8 {
  margin-left: 66.6666666667%;
}

.col-9 {
  flex: 0 0 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
}

.col-offset-9 {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
  flex: 0 0 83.3333333333%;
  max-width: 83.3333333333%;
}

.col-offset-10 {
  margin-left: 83.3333333333%;
}

.col-11 {
  flex: 0 0 91.6666666667%;
  max-width: 91.6666666667%;
}

.col-offset-11 {
  margin-left: 91.6666666667%;
}

.col-12 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.col-offset-12 {
  margin-left: 100%;
}
```